# Is there a way to make a DC to low voltage AC circuit

Tags: transformer, ac, dc

All the circuits I see online are like 12v DC -> 220v AC or something along those lines but I'm only looking for something like 9v DC to 9v AC. Is this possible?

Comment: You should describe what you need this for and specify the requirements.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @Rev there are not really any requirements. I would like this because I'm not experienced enough to work with wall power ill probably kill myself if I try.

Comment: @brhans Would I do 9v DC -> 9v AC or 9v DC -> 220V AC -> 9v AC

Comment: 9Vdc -> 9Vac. Build an oscillator and couple the output through a capacitor or drive a transformer, depending on your requirements.

Comment: @brhans Ah got it. Thank you! (Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?)

Comment: What kind of AC you need? Sine wave?Will square wave do?

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/ might be a good resource to understand DC, AC, frequency, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to generate AC from DC. It all depends on what you want or need.
Basically every audio amplifier generates AC from DC. From the tiny amplifier in your mobile device of choice to your stereo set in your livingroom. They even do it with variable amplitude and frequency.

Also, oscillators for generating frequencies (used as clock for a CPU ar anything else) are generatring AC (often with a DC-Offset) from DC.

BLDC motor drivers are also generating AC from DC (mostly in the range of safety low voltage). So AC to DC conversion is all around you all the time.

In the simplest case it's just switching on and off the DC at a given frequency. From there you can go fancier by making it bipolar (positive and negative voltages) and giving your AC waveform a shape other than rectangular (like for example a sine wave form).

The circuits to generate high voltage AC or low voltage ar not that different. If you want low volatage you basically just leave out the part the increases the voltage (and maybe some feedback components)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foVJio.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a very simple oscillator (the inverter should ideally be one with a schmitt-trigger input). This gives you a rectangular AC between Vcc and GND with a frequency that depends on the value of the capacitor and the resistor (the choosen values would lead to a frequency of around 1kHz)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqmYdD.png)</sup>

This circuit should generate a symmetrical tringular wave output.

And if you want to know how to make a sine wave from a triangle, I can only suggest reading Ken Shirriff's great [blog post](https://www.righto.com/2022/03/reverse-engineering-waveform-generator.html) on reverse engineering an old function generator circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples of power inverter circuits that you can build for converting DC to AC. The basic circuits provide a rather crude approximation of AC. You can also find oscillator circuits that you can build. You could also buy a doorbell transformer that will provide up to three values of low-voltage AC. The 220 volt side is isolated from the low voltage side, so they are quite safe, but you would need to safely attach a 220 volt cord and plug. There are transformers for toy trains that have the plug already attached and provide a variable-voltage AC output. One of those would be an ideal AC source for a beginner.